# How to show UITableView below a UITextField using swift programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So I have this `UITextField` and I want to show a `UITableView` just below it. I'm trying to show the suggestions in the `UITableView` my logic works fine but I want to know how can I show the `UITableView` beneath the `UITextField`.

Currently, I'm doing something like this

```
 private func setUpAutoCompleteTable() {
        autocompleteTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: self.originTextField.bounds.minX,y: self.originTextField.bounds.maxY,width: self.originTextField.bounds.width,height: self.originTextField.bounds.height * 4), style: UITableView.Style.plain)
        self.view.addSubview(autocompleteTableView)
        
        autocompleteTableView.delegate = self
        autocompleteTableView.dataSource = self
        autocompleteTableView.isScrollEnabled = true
        autocompleteTableView.isHidden = true
        autocompleteTableView.register(LocationAutoCompleteCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "AutoCompleteRowIdentifier")
    }
```

But it is showing the table at the top of the screen. I want to tell you that `originTextField` is inside another view.

**UPDATE**

This is how the view hierarchy looks.

[image]

Comment: are you laying out your UI in storyboards or programmatically?

Comment: So, I have done everything in `storyboards` just the table view is programmatically.

Comment: is the tableView laid out in the storyboard as well, and you're just trying to modify it in the VIewController? or are you trying to set it up completely programmatically?

Comment: No, I'm trying to set it up completely programmatically.

Comment: which view is originTextField in? You need to reference the outer view instead. The self.originTextField.bounds.maxY gives you the relative Y position in the superView of originTextField.

Comment: @JVS please look at the updated question.

Comment: @VarunRaj I can't seem to find the UIElements of autocompleteTableView and originTextField in your view hierarchy. Please share the full hierarchy.

Comment: @JVS that's because I'm adding `UITableView` programmatically and `originTextField` is `origin` in the picture.

Comment: to which view are you adding the UITableView? Please provide some code

Comment: @JVS I have added the whole method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207473/discussion-between-jvs-and-varun-raj).

Answer (score -1):

So, to layout the tableView programmatically you need to declare it in your ViewController

```
var autoCompleteTableView: UITableView!
```

Initialize it in ViewDidLoad

```
autoCompleteTableView = UITableView(frame: .zero) // constraints will set the frame for us later
```

set constraints in ViewDidLoad

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    autoCompleteTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.bottomAnchor, constant: 5), //the constant is how many pts below the textField you want the tableView to be
    autoCompleteTableView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
    autoCompleteTableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
    autoCompleteTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
])
```

and then you can set whatever tableView properties you need to.  remember, your VC also needs to implement `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`

Comment: `originTextField ` is in another view. Constrain will work if they are not inside the same view?

Comment: Hey! Thanks. I got what you did. Can you please take a took at the updated question?

Comment: As long as they're in the same view hierarchy it's fine, and they should, since they're both in the same viewcontroller

Answer (score -1):

You should probably go for Gabe's answer with a detail, considering that the textfield is inside another view.

So, you'll need to get the textfield's bottom anchor reference from the Storyboard. You can do that by control dragging the constraint to your swift file.

Then you can do this:

```
autoCompleteTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.textFieldBottomAnchorReference, constant: 5)
```

Comment: It makes sense but I want to show `UITableView` beneath a bunch of `UITextFields`.